# Animation в firefox

Tags: css, css3, анимация, firefox

Вот собственно код: http://jsbin.com/EjUNEDe/1/edit

В google chrome если скрыть блок с анимацией и показать его, то анимация начнется заново.
В mozilla firefox анимация воспроизводится только 1  раз, и скрытие-показ не начинают её заново. Как заставить лису воспроизводить анимацию при этом заново?

Comment: http://css-tricks.com/restart-css-animation/

Comment: лиса не воспринимает это

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Добавьте к видимому элементу класс visible и вешайте анимацию на .a.visible

http://jsbin.com/EjUNEDe/10/edit

Answer (score 0):

Нужно добавить свойство к `.a {animation-iteration-count: infinite;}`

Comment: Теперь она бесконечная, а мне нужно чтоб она повторялась только 1 раз

Comment: Вместо infinite поставь нужное количество повторений.